# Action of the modular group on upper triangular matrices (from the right)

Tags: matrix-equations

I am considering the (finite) set of upper triangular matrices
$$D_N=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&d\end{pmatrix}:a,b,d\in\mathbb{Z}, ad=N, \gcd(a,b,d)=1, 0\leq b<d\right\},$$
which arises in various questions to do with modular functions, etc, as it represents all of $\operatorname{GL}_2^+(\mathbb{Q})$ (Edit: well, the determinant-$N$ part), up to the action of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ from the left.

There is also an action of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ on $D_N$ from the right.

Namely, given $g\in D_N$ and $\gamma\in\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, the matrix $g\gamma$ is still a primitive integer matrix of determinant $N$, and hence (a standard fact) takes the form $\gamma' h$ for some $\gamma'\in\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ and unique $h\in D_N$.  So let $\gamma$ act on $D_N$ by sending each $g$ to the corresponding $h$.

The question is: is this action transitive?  I thought this was a standard fact, and one seems to need it to prove that the $N$th modular polynomial $\Phi_N$ is irreducible (among other things).

However, I can't seem to find a reference for it, and after struggling for a short time to prove it, I am increasingly pessimistic - it seems to rely on some properties of the "3-variable Euclidean algorithm" that I'm not certain I believe in.

(It would be enough to know, for instance, that one can write
$$a\lambda m + bmn + dn\mu=1,$$
for some integers $\lambda, \mu,m,n$, but this doesn't seem particularly likely to hold in general - the Euclidean algorithm gets us close to this but not quite there.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered after I reposted the question to MathOverflow:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273919/action-of-sl2-z-on-upper-triangular-primitive-integer-matrices-of-determinant

Thanks to David Speyer and GH from MO (and any potential answers yet to come!) for their responses there.